# View update raises ORA-01733

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database

I created a view and then I want to update the cost and show the error. But it reterns that virtual column not allowed.

View:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CONCERT_EVENTS1 AS
 SELECT CONCERT.CONCERT_ID, EVENT.EVENT_ID, CONCERT.NAME, EVENT.DATE1 , CONCERT.DURATION,
 CONCERT.TYPE, TO_CHAR(CONCERT.COST, 'L9,999.99') AS FORMATED_COST
 FROM EVENT
 INNER JOIN CONCERT
 ON CONCERT.CONCERT_ID = EVENT.CONCERT_ID;
```

Below is the error:
Error starting at line 1 in command:

```
UPDATE CONCERT_EVENTS1
SET formated_cost = '300.00'
WHERE formated_cost = '200.00'

Error at Command Line:2 Column:5
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here
01733. 00000 -  "virtual column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> FORMATED_COST is probably a calculated field, or in any case the
>   database cannot infer what change is to be made to the tables
>   underlying the view based on the change you are requiring.

Comment: so there is no solution?

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54776

Answer (score 0):

Include an extra column in your view on CONCERT.COST without the formatting. And update only that new column. The explanation of why this is needed is given by Vignesh Kumar.